# css - give bottom border to label & textbox combo

Tags: html, css

I want to have border to my label text and its associated textbox. I have used `border-bottom` property but because my label is padded to left its border is not right below it.

html

```
<div>
    <span class="elements">
        <label class="field" for="Title">Title</label>
        <input name="Title" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="Mr">
    </span>
</div>
```

css

```
.elements {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #1f6a9a;
}

.field {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #b6d6ed;
    padding-left: 44px;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
}

input {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0 solid;
    height: 25px;
    width: 300px;
    color: #b6d6ed;
}
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2HARy/

**I want to have border start from "Title" text only**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `padding-left: 44px` from the `.field` element and use a `margin` on the *parent* element instead. In doing so, the border will start at "title".

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/9TeEG/)

```
.elements {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 44px;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #1f6a9a;
}
.field {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #b6d6ed;
}
```

Additionally, if you want the border to start ***directly*** at the text, remove the `padding-left` on the `.elements` element. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/C8mxm/).

Comment: sometimes, `margin` can't replace the `padding` (like in this case) such as when we need some `background-image` to cover the padding.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `padding-left:44px` there is no way to have the border start from the "Title" text. What you must do is remove that property from `.elements`, wrap `.elements` in a `div`, and apply the `padding-left` property to that div.

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3TChG/